# How to solve $y' = \sqrt {x+y+1}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How does one solve $y' = \sqrt{x+y+1}$? I try substituting $v=x+y+1$ and using substitution methods, but it turned out to be so messy.

Answer (score 7):

Hints: Make the substitution:

$$v = x + y$$

So,

$$v' = 1+ y' \rightarrow y' = v'-1$$

Substitute into original DEQ and get:

$$v' = \sqrt{v+1} + 1$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: No.. all I meet in the end $\int dv/(1+\sqrt {v+1})$...

Comment: @vop Try $v+1=s^2$

Comment: I tried substituting u=v+1, but that leads me into another problem. ...

Comment: That substitution works and leads to one more substitution as does the one @GitGud mentions. Note, the result is somewhat nasty at the end.

Comment: Nice hint. That does the job! +1

Answer (score 2):

Another substitution is $x+y+1 = z^2$, so $1+y' = 2zz'$, from which $y' = 2zz'-1$:
$$
2zz'-1 = z \\
2zz' = z+1 \\
\frac {2zdz}{z+1} = dx \\
\int \left (1-\frac 1{z+1} \right ) dz = \frac 12\int dx \\
z - \ln \left |z+1 \right | = \frac x2 + C
$$
Starting this point, it makes sense to leave a solution as an implicit equation w.r.t $x,y$, so
$$
\sqrt{x+y+1} - \ln \left ( \sqrt{x+y+1}+1\right ) - \frac x2 = C
$$

Answer (score 0):

As written by Kaster, you can express $y$ as a function of $x$. It involves the Lambert function. Try using Wolfram Alpha.